# Pasando múltiples parámetros de la expresión regular de una URL a la definición de la vista en Django

Tags: python, django, regex

Tengo el siguiente modelo llamado LodgingOffer, mediante el cual es posible crear una oferta de alojamiento y detallar sus datos:

```
class LodgingOffer(models.Model):

    # Foreign Key to my User model      
    created_by = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    ad_title = models.CharField(null=False, blank=False,
        max_length=255, verbose_name='Título de la oferta')

    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=100, blank=True)

    country = CountryField(blank_label='(Seleccionar país)', verbose_name='Pais')

    city = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank = False, verbose_name='Ciudad')

    def __str__(self):
        return "%s" % self.ad_title

    pub_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True,)

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('host:detail', kwargs = {'slug' : self.slug })

# I assign slug to offer based in ad_title field,checking if slug exist
def create_slug(instance, new_slug=None):
    slug = slugify(instance.ad_title)
    if new_slug is not None:
        slug = new_slug
    qs = LodgingOffer.objects.filter(slug=slug).order_by("-id")
    exists = qs.exists()
    if exists:
        new_slug = "%s-%s" % (slug, qs.first().id)
        return create_slug(instance, new_slug=new_slug)
    return slug

# Brefore to save, assign slug to offer created above.
def pre_save_article_receiver(sender, instance, *args, **kwargs):
    if not instance.slug:
        instance.slug = create_slug(instance)

pre_save.connect(pre_save_article_receiver, sender=LodgingOffer)
```

Para este modelo, tengo una vista de detalle llamada `HostingOfferDetailView` en la cual muestro los datos de una oferta de un objeto `LodgingOffer`

Un importante objetivo que quiero perseguir y por el cual formulo esta pregunta es que en la vista de detalle de un objeto `LodgingOffer` yo debo poder contactar al dueño de esa oferta (objeto `LodgingOffer` - usuario quien lo creó-) para que otro usuario interesado pueda aplicar a ella.

Para este propósito, tengo la función `contact_owner_offer()` la cual es una función en donde envío un correo electrónico al dueño de esta oferta.

Todo esto lo estoy haciendo en la vista de detalle `HostingOfferDetailView` de esta manera:

```
class HostingOfferDetailView(UserProfileDataMixin, LoginRequiredMixin, DetailView):
    model = LodgingOffer
    template_name = 'lodgingoffer_detail.html'
    context_object_name = 'lodgingofferdetail'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(HostingOfferDetailView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        user = self.request.user

        # LodgingOffer object
        #lodging_offer_owner = self.get_object()

        # Get the full name of the lodging offer owner        
        lodging_offer_owner_full_name = self.get_object().created_by.get_long_name()

        # Get the lodging offer email owner
        lodging_offer_owner_email = self.get_object().created_by.email

        # Get the lodging offer title
        lodging_offer_title = self.get_object().ad_title

        # Get the user interested email in lodging offer
        user_interested_email = user.email

        # Get the user interested full name 
        user_interested_full_name = user.get_long_name()

        context['user_interested_email'] = user_interested_email
        context['lodging_offer_owner_email'] = lodging_offer_owner_email

        # Send the data (lodging_offer_owner_email
        # user_interested_email and lodging_offer_title) presented 
        # above to the contact_owner_offer function
        contact_owner_offer(self.request, lodging_offer_owner_email,
                    user_interested_email, lodging_offer_title)

        return context
```

Mi función `contact_owner_offer` recibe estos parámetros de oferta y envia el correo al dueño de la oferta o quien la publicó, de la siguiente manera:

```
def contact_owner_offer(request, lodging_offer_owner_email, user_interested_email, lodging_offer_title):
    user = request.user
    print("a", lodging_offer_owner_email, user_interested_email)
    if user.is_authenticated:
        print('Send email')
        mail_subject = 'Interesados en tu oferta'

        context = {
            'lodging_offer_owner_email': lodging_offer_owner_email,
            # usuario dueño de la oferta  TO

            'offer': lodging_offer_title,
            # oferta por la que se pregunta

            'user_interested_email': user_interested_email,
            # usuario interesado en la oferta

            'domain': settings.SITE_URL,
            'request': request
        }

        message = render_to_string('contact_user_own_offer.html', context)
        #to_email = lodging_offer_owner.email,

        send_mail(mail_subject, message, settings.DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL,
              [lodging_offer_owner_email], fail_silently=True)

        # email = EmailMessage(mail_subject, message, to=[to_email])
        # email.send()
    # return redirect('articles:article_list')
```

Esto lo he hecho a modo de prueba y hasta aquí todo resulta como he querido, y el resultado es que cuando entro al URL de detalle de una oferta objeto `LodgingOffer`, se envía un correo electrónico al dueño de dicha oferta.

Lo que deseo es que en mi template de detalle de oferta, tener un botón el cual diga **"Contactar al dueño de la oferta"** y que cualquier usuario que lo presione, acto seguido se envíe un correo electrónico al dueño de la oferta.

Para esto, he procedido a definir un URL que llame a la función `contact_owner_offer()` y que sea llamado desde el atributo `href` de un boton en mi template:

El URL, (**acorde a mi entendimiento y es aquí en donde reside la duda y el motivo de mi pregunta**) lo he definido acorde al número de parámetros que recibe la función `contact_owner_offer()`

Esto significa que mi URL debe recibir:

- El email del propietario de la oferta
- El email del usuario interesado en la oferta
- El titulo de la oferta, aunque para esto estoy enviándole el slug de ese título, **no se si eso sea correcto**

Entoces, acorde a lo anterior, he creado este URL:

```
url(r'^contact-to-owner/(?P<email>[\w.@+-]+)/from/'
    r'(?P<interested_email>[\w.@+-]+)/(?P<slug>[\w-]+)/$',
    contact_owner_offer, name='contact_owner_offer'),
```

Seguidamente, en mi template, genero un boton html en donde llamo a esta URL enviándole sus respectivos parámetros:

```
<div class="contact">
    <a class="contact-button" href="{% url 'host:contact_owner_offer' email=lodging_offer_owner_email interested_email=user_interested_email slug=lodgingofferdetail.slug %}">
        <img src="{% static 'img/icons/contact.svg' %}" alt="">
        <span>Contactar</span>
    </a>
</div>
```

Lo que me sucede es que cuando entro al template de detalle de oferta y hago clic en el boton de **Contactar** referenciando inmediatamente anterior, tengo el siguiente mensaje de error:

```
TypeError: contact_owner_offer() got an unexpected keyword argument 'email'
[10/Oct/2017 01:04:06] "GET /host/contact-to-owner/botibagl@gmail.com/from/ces@ces.edu.co/apartacho/ HTTP/1.1" 500 77979
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo que no comprendo, es porque me dice que mi URL no espera un argumento llamado `email` que es en donde le paso el parámetro `email=lodging_offer_owner_email` a través del boton en el template.

Agradezco cualquier orientación

**ACTUALIZACIÓN**

Acorde a las recomendaciones dadas he cambiado ligeramente la definición de mi URL especificando el nombre del argumento o keyword argument que estoy pasando.

Mi función es:

```
def contact_owner_offer(request, lodging_offer_owner_email, user_interested_email, slug):
    user = request.user
    print("a", lodging_offer_owner_email, user_interested_email, slug)
    if user.is_authenticated:
        print('Send email')
        mail_subject = 'Interesados en tu oferta'

        context = {
            'lodging_offer_owner_email': lodging_offer_owner_email,
            # usuario dueño de la oferta  TO

            'offer': slug,
            # oferta por la que se pregunta

            'user_interested_email': user_interested_email,
            # usuario interesado en la oferta

            'domain': settings.SITE_URL,
            'request': request
        }

        message = render_to_string('contact_user_own_offer.html', context)
        #to_email = lodging_offer_owner.email,

        send_mail(mail_subject, message, settings.DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL,
                  [lodging_offer_owner_email], fail_silently=True)
```

La definición de mi URL ha quedado así:

```
url(r'^contact-to-owner/(?P<lodging_offer_owner_email>[\w.@+-]+)/from/'
    r'(?P<interested_email>[\w.@+-]+)/(?P<slug>[\w-]+)/$',
    contact_owner_offer,
    name='contact_owner_offer'
),
```

En mi template html ha quedado asi, el valor del parámetro slug, lo tomo a través del context_object_name que defino en la clase `HostingOfferDetailView` por lo cual queda `lodgingofferdetail.slug`:

```
<div class="contact">
    <a class="contact-button" href="{% url 'host:contact_owner_offer' lodging_offer_owner_email=lodging_offer_owner_email interested_email=user_interested_email slug=lodgingofferdetail.slug %}">
        <img src="{% static 'img/icons/contact.svg' %}" alt="">
        <span>Contactar</span>
    </a>
</div>
```

Y al posicionarme sobre el botón obtengo en el url el valor de los parámetros que estoy manejando

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Solo que cuando le doy clic a ese botón, vuelvo al mismo error:

```
Traceback:

File "/home/bgarcial/.virtualenvs/hostayni/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py" in inner
  42.             response = get_response(request)

File "/home/bgarcial/.virtualenvs/hostayni/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _get_response
  187.                 response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)

File "/home/bgarcial/.virtualenvs/hostayni/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _get_response
  185.                 response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

Exception Type: TypeError at /host/contact-to-owner/botibagl@gmail.com/from/fabiola.quimica@gmail.com/apartacho/
Exception Value: contact_owner_offer() got an unexpected keyword argument 'interested_email'
```

Comment: El error es porque en el regex estás creando 2 grupos con el mismo nombre. Se soluciona modificando el nombre de uno, por ejemplo `(?P<email2>`...`)`... No sé si eso responde a tu pregunta.

Comment: @Mariano si, muchas gracias, ahora mi `URL` esta bien formado acorde a tu recomendación. Tengo este inconveniente adicional que me atrevo a comentar y es que no se como debo llamar este `URL` desde el ateibuto `href` en un template html, ya que mi idea es convertir esta acción a que se dispare por medio de un boton en un template

Comment: @Mariano, por el momento, estoy intentando esto en el atributo href: `{% url 'host:contact_owner_offer' email=lodgingofferdetail.created_by.email email=user_interested_email slug=lodgingofferdetail.slug %}`  pero obtengo un `NoReverseMatch`. Si puedes darme una orientación te lo agradezco :)

Comment: Ahí ya no sé, pero quizás otro pueda ayudarte. ¿No deberías llamar `email2` a uno de estos también? Probablemente te convenga editar la pregunta con esa info para orientarla a lo que estés buscando.

Comment: La idea de usar regex en urls, es que al crear un grupo, este, con el nombre del grupo es pasado como un parametro de llave valor a la función la cual está encargada de renderizar la vista, es decir, si en tu url, defines un grupo con el nombre `email`, es porque en la vista, tienes un parametro llamado `email`, e internamente lo que django hace es `tu_funcion_vista(request, email=email)` el error que ves, es porque esos nombres no están haciendo el match correcto

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Me parece que el problema aquí es similar a tu [pregunta anterior](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/108431/100). Tienes que usar los mismos parámetros en la definición de la vista:

```
def contact_owner_offer(request, email, interested_email, slug):
    ....
```

No te compliques, es como crear una función cualquiera y le pases los parámetros equivocados:

```
>>> def foo(bar):
...     print bar
... 
>>> foo(bar=10)
10
>>> foo(bar2=10)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: foo() got an unexpected keyword argument 'bar2'
```

Y eso es lo que hace `{% url %}`, simplemente le pasa los parámetros a la función, pero estos parámetros deben llamarse igual.

Comment: Cesar, entiendo, manejo básico de funciones en cuanto a paso de parámetros por referencia, es verdad eso me faltaba. Pero ahora volví al error inicial, puedes ver mi actualización por favor?

Comment: @bgarcial tal vez sea que en tu función has definido el parámetro como `user_interested_email` cuando debería ser simplemente `interested_email`. Recuerda que la función, la llamada desde el template usando `{% url %}` y la definición de tu URL deben tener los mismos nombres.