# Llamando a una Django URL de múltiples parámetros desde un boton en un template html

Tags: python, django, django-urls

Tengo este URL que recibe tres parámetros

```
url(r'^contact-to-owner/(?P<email>[\w.@+-]+)/'
        r'(?P<interested_email>[\w.@+-]+)/(?P<slug>[\w-]+)/$',
        contact_owner_offer, name='contact_owner_offer'),
```

¿Cómo debo llamar este URL desde un template html?

Lo estoy haciendo de esta manera:

```
<div class="contact">
    <a class="contact-button" href="{% url 'host:contact_owner_offer' email=lodgingofferdetail.created_by.email email2=user_interested_email slug=lodgingofferdetail.slug %}">
        <img src="{% static 'img/icons/contact.svg' %}" alt="">
        <span>Contactar</span>
    </a>
</div>
```

Pero obtengo este mensaje:

```
django.urls.exceptions.NoReverseMatch: Reverse for 'contact_owner_offer' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{'email': 'botibagl@gmail.com', 'email2': 'botibagl@gmail.com', 'slug': 'apartacho'}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['host/contact-to-owner/(?P<email>[\\w.@+-]+)/(?P<interested_email>[\\w.@+-]+)/(?P<slug>[\\w-]+)/$']
[09/Oct/2017 22:56:42] "GET /host/lodging-offer/apartacho/ HTTP/1.1" 500 202205
```

¿Cómo debo darle a entender desde el template que este URL espera esos tres parámetros?

Comment: Hola, ¿por qué estás usando `email2` en vez de `interested_email` como veo que lo has definido en la URL?

Comment: @César es cierto, debe haber un match en el nombre de los parámetros tanto en la definición del URL como en el llamado a ésta. Muchas gracias.

Comment: @César me tomo el atrevimiento de pedirte si puedes ver esta pregunta que he hecho que es relacionada con el llamado a esta misma URL que defino acá.  Es esta y no entiendo un inconveniente que me surge. https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/108425/expresiones-regulares-pasando-múltiples-parámetros-a-una-url-en-django Agradezco tu ayuda

Answer (score 2):

Recuerda que los parámetros que definas tienen que tener el mismo nombre que has definido en tu URL:

```
url(r'^contact-to-owner/(?P<email>[\w.@+-]+)/'
        r'(?P<interested_email>[\w.@+-]+)/(?P<slug>[\w-]+)/$',
        contact_owner_offer, name='contact_owner_offer'),
```

Por lo tanto, tu llamada a la función desde el template debería ser:

```
<div class="contact">
    <a class="contact-button" href="{% url 'host:contact_owner_offer' email=lodgingofferdetail.created_by.email interested_email=user_interested_email slug=lodgingofferdetail.slug %}">
        <img src="{% static 'img/icons/contact.svg' %}" alt="">
        <span>Contactar</span>
    </a>
</div>
```